# How to code java program that input ends with symbol semicolon. Input example: Stack 7 4 2 3 * + ;

Tags: java, stack

The Postfix Evaluator is a program that receives a postfix expression and calculate the value of the
expression. The postfix form represents a natural way to evaluate expressions because precedence rules
are not required. The black box shown below represents the Postfix Evaluator. If we give the input 4 2 3 *
+, the program will give the output 10. My task is to write a program for postfix evaluator with ***The input ends with symbol semicolon***. Input
example:
Stack 7
4 2 3 * + ;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String p;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        p=s.nextLine();
        while(!(p.equals(";"))) {
        Stack<Integer> st=new Stack<Integer>();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(p);
        int a,b,c;
        String operator;

        while(sc.hasNext()==true) {

            if(sc.hasNextInt()==true)
                st.push(sc.nextInt());

            else
            {
                operator=sc.next().trim();
                a=st.pop();
                b=st.pop();

                switch (operator)
                {

                case "^" :
                    c=(int) Math.pow(b,a);
                    st.push(c);
                    break;

                case "%" :

                    c=b%a;
                    st.push(c);
                    break;

                case "*" :
                    c=b*a;
                    st.push(c);
                    break;
                case "/" :
                    c=b/a;
                    st.push(c);
                    break;

                case "+" :
                    c=b+a;
                    st.push(c);
                    break;

                case "-" :
                    c=b-a;
                    st.push(c);
                    break;


                } // switch



            } //else

        }//while loop

        int result;
        result=st.pop();
        System.out.println(result);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain where you're having trouble with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: i just having the trouble to add condition where inputs end with semicolon( the input must end with ;)

Comment: Again: please read [mcve] and enhance your **question** accordingly by editing it. "having trouble to add condition" ... isn't a problem description we can help with.

Comment: @GhostCat - The example is complete and verifiable.

Comment: @Armali The point of mcve is to not only give, code but also clearly lay out what the problem is, in terms of expected versus actual output.

Answer (score 0):

> i just having the trouble to add condition where inputs end with semicolon( the input must end with ;)

If it's nothing more… The `;` gets read in as `operator`, so after the line

```
                operator=sc.next().trim();
```

add

```
                if (operator.equals(";")) { p = ";"; break; }
```

in order to get out of the inner and later also the outer `while` loop.